# Is this phrase gramatically correct? [sb] found [sb]to not only have a [] but able to [] due to [] and []

Tags: grammar

For example: [Amy] found [Bob] to not only have a [good sense of humour] but able to [do other impressive things] due to [Bob's personality] and [wealth]

The above is just a random example where I filled in the blanks. The structure I wanted to ask if it was grammatically correct is in the title.

See, I'm a native speaker of English and I used this structure in passing when writing to a friend (ESL learner) who says I'm wrong to use it like that, whereas I think it sounds right, but can't explain why.

Help pls? Thx guys.

Comment: Try to be more specific as to what you suspect could be "wrong". One can only ask one question per post.

Comment: Very late comment, but one clear problem (not addressed in the answer below) is that the second element is lacking a required helping verb; if you remove the 'not only' bit, it becomes  "Amy found Bob to able to do other things...".

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, English speakers are taught not to split infinitives, that is, not to put anything between *to* and its verb.  That may be what your friend is objecting too.  But the ban on split infinitives is (rightly, in my opinion) derided by a large number of linguists and grammarians.

To my mind, the more substantive issue is with the use of *not only*.  For perfect parallelism, the construction should be either of the following:

> *I found Bob not ADJ but ADJ*.
>
> *I found Bob to not only VERB but VERB*.

You’ve mixed the two: *I found Bob to not only VERB but ADJ*.  So, if you fill in the ellipsis here (which is everything up to *not only*), you end up with:

> *I found Bob to not only VERB but* [*I found Bob to*] *ADJ*.

Needless to say, *I found Bob to ADJ* is ungrammatical, which means that the large structure is also ungrammatical.

One solution is, for once, to follow the proscription against infinitive splitting:

> *I found Bob not only to have a good sense of humour, but able to dodge flying arrows*.

But I’m not crazy about the mixed construction.  I think a better option is to turn the adjectival phrase *able to* into a verbal phrase, *to be able to*, so that you have two verb phrases:

> *I found Bob not only to have a good sense of humour, but to be able to dodge flying arrows*.

Comment: haha. thanks for your answer. still a teensy confused, i mean, my [] could have been put in different places. So if I said:

[Amy] found [Bob] to not only [have (verb) a good sense of humour] but able to [do (verb) other impressive things] due to Bob's [personality (noun)] and [wealth(noun)]

Then it would make sense according to your parallelism? 

Also, you're a native English speaker right? Did you understand what I was trying to say?

Comment: I think I understand.  Yes, I'm a native speaker, multiply published.  I missed out the adjunct _due to blah_ from my answer because it's irrelevant to the grammaticality and stylistics of the sentence.  Leave it in, miss it out, your choice.